# M2 Mac YOLOv8 Training: RuntimeError: "upsample_nearest2d_channels_last" not implemented for 'Half'

Tags: runtime-error, yolo, training-data, yolov8, half-precision-float

I want to train a Yolov8 model on a custom dataset with my Mac and this is my first time working on deep learning. Unfortunately, I experienced an error,

`RuntimeError: "upsample_nearest2d_channels_last" not implemented for 'Half'`.

I read some similar issues&solutions online when people were using stable diffusion and I believe I need to change my float point from 16 to 32. I know I can disable half precision (FP16) during the validation process by input argument half=False, but there isn't during the training process. I would be very grateful if someone could help.

**My code:**

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt') 

results = model.train(data='MY_PATH/data.yaml', epochs=20, imgsz=640, device='mps')
```

**Error:**

```
New https://pypi.org/project/ultralytics/8.1.15 available  Update with 'pip install -U ultralytics'
Ultralytics YOLOv8.1.11  Python-3.12.0 torch-2.2.0 MPS (Apple M2)
engine/trainer: task=detect, mode=train, model=yolov8n.pt, data=/Users/victor/Desktop/object_recognition/shoe-detection-1/data.yaml, epochs=20, time=None, patience=50, batch=16, imgsz=640, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=mps, workers=8, project=None, name=train23, exist_ok=False, pretrained=True, optimizer=auto, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, freeze=None, multi_scale=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, vid_stride=1, stream_buffer=False, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, embed=None, show=False, save_frames=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, show_boxes=True, line_width=None, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, auto_augment=randaugment, erasing=0.4, crop_fraction=1.0, cfg=None, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs/detect/train23
Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=4

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.SPPF            [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Concat           [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    752092  ultralytics.nn.modules.head.Detect           [4, [64, 128, 256]]           
Model summary: 225 layers, 3011628 parameters, 3011612 gradients

Transferred 319/355 items from pretrained weights
Freezing layer 'model.22.dfl.conv.weight'
train: Scanning /Users/victor/Desktop/object_recognition/shoe-detection-1/train/labels.cache... 29 images, 1 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|███
val: Scanning /Users/victor/Desktop/object_recognition/shoe-detection-1/valid/labels.cache... 8 images, 0 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████
Plotting labels to runs/detect/train23/labels.jpg... 
optimizer: 'optimizer=auto' found, ignoring 'lr0=0.01' and 'momentum=0.937' and determining best 'optimizer', 'lr0' and 'momentum' automatically... 
optimizer: AdamW(lr=0.00125, momentum=0.9) with parameter groups 57 weight(decay=0.0), 64 weight(decay=0.0005), 63 bias(decay=0.0)
Image sizes 640 train, 640 val
Using 0 dataloader workers
Logging results to runs/detect/train23
Starting training for 20 epochs...

      Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size
  0%|          | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:4001: UserWarning: MPS: passing scale factor to upsample ops is supported natively starting from macOS 13.0. Falling back on CPU. This may have performance implications. (Triggered internally at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/mps/operations/UpSample.mm:246.)
  return torch._C._nn.upsample_nearest2d(input, output_size, scale_factors)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/functional.py:905: UserWarning: MPS: _unique2 op is supported natively starting from macOS 13.0. Falling back on CPU. This may have performace implications. (Triggered internally at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/mps/operations/Unique.mm:323.)
  output, inverse_indices, counts = torch._unique2(
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ultralytics/utils/loss.py:183: UserWarning: MPS: nonzero op is supported natively starting from macOS 13.0. Falling back on CPU. This may have performance implications. (Triggered internally at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/mps/operations/Indexing.mm:283.)
  out[j, :n] = targets[matches, 1:]
       1/20         0G      1.435      3.329      1.606         62        640: 100%|██████████| 2/2 [00:03<00:00,  1.73s/it]
                 Class     Images  Instances      Box(P          R      mAP50  mAP50-95):   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/victor/Desktop/object recognition/training.py", line 7, in <module>
    results = model.train(data='/Users/victor/Desktop/object_recognition/shoe-detection-1/data.yaml', epochs=20, imgsz=640, device='mps')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/model.py", line 601, in train
    self.trainer.train()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/trainer.py", line 208, in train
    self._do_train(world_size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/trainer.py", line 424, in _do_train
    self.metrics, self.fitness = self.validate()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/trainer.py", line 543, in validate
    metrics = self.validator(self)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/validator.py", line 176, in __call__
    preds = model(batch["img"], augment=augment)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ultralytics/nn/tasks.py", line 80, in forward
    return self.predict(x, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ultralytics/nn/tasks.py", line 98, in predict
    return self._predict_once(x, profile, visualize, embed)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ultralytics/nn/tasks.py", line 119, in _predict_once
    x = m(x)  # run
        ^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/upsampling.py", line 157, in forward
    return F.interpolate(input, self.size, self.scale_factor, self.mode, self.align_corners,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 4001, in interpolate
    return torch._C._nn.upsample_nearest2d(input, output_size, scale_factors)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: "upsample_nearest2d_channels_last" not implemented for 'Half'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my MAC M1, and simply upgrading my mac version from 13 to the latest currently (14.3.1) fixed the problem, try upgrading your mac version to the latest.